# Viewing record before updating in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I want to update my database records. Before carrying out the update, I want to show all affected data to the user as in the image below:

[image: Update Subcategories]

Instead of showing *Category ID*, I want to show the *Category Name*.

I've made the relationship between *category* and *subcategory*.

I have a `AdminController` controller through which I'm passing data to the view.

Below is the content of my `AdminController` controller:

```
public function getUpdateSubcategory()
{
    $subcatgry = subcategory::all();
    return view('admin/UpdateSubcategory', ['subcategory' => $subcatgry]);
}
```

This is my view file:

[image: View image showing data]

![Controller Image retrieving and passing value to view][3]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Write it as..

```
@foreach($subcategory as $subcategories)
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"> Edit </a></td>
    <td> {{ $subcategories->subcategory_name }} </td>
    <td> {{ $subcategories->category_id}} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

You can not use same variable name in the iterating foreach loop.. So just changed the name of the second variable.

Comment: without changing variable it is showing me records i just want to show category NAME instead of category ID. how to get this can Anyone ANSWER that. just code for that.